# Uncaught TypeError: FormData constructor: Argument 1 is not an object

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

Hi I have a fetch request to my php script but an error occurs when I try to submit form data via html. How can I solve my problem? thank

```
const formdata = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
const submit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('script.php', {
        method: 'GET',
        body: formdata,
    })
        .then(ans => ans.text())
        .then(table => document.querySelector('#ans').innerHTML = table);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.querySelector('#submitButton').addEventListener('click', submit);
});




<form id="form" method="GET">
    <div class="inputX centered">
        <label for><div>X:</div></label>
        <div class="form_radio_group">
            <div class="form_radio_group-item">
                <input id="radio-1" type="radio" name="x_set" value="1" checked>
                <label for="radio-1">1</label>
```

Comment: Your script is running before the document is rendered, so at the point where you call `new FormData` the form doesn't exist yet. Move it inside the submit handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is running before the document is rendered, so at the point where you call `new FormData` the form doesn't exist yet. Move it inside the submit handler, or better yet, just get it from the event:

```js
const submit = function(e) {
    const formdata = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('script.php', {
```

or

```js
const submit = function (e) {
    const formdata = new FormData(e.target.form);
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('script.php', {
```

I'd also recommend that you put an `onsubmit` on the form (or listen for submit events on the form) instead of listening for clicks on the submit button. This way your handler will fire even if the form is submitted via some other interaction, like hitting enter on an input, clicking a different submit button, etc.

---

To use FormData in a GET request without a body, construct a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instance and use its toString method to get a query string to append to your URL:

```js
const formdata = new FormData(event.target);
const queryString = new URLSearchParams(formdata).toString();
fetch(`script.php?${queryString}`, {
```

Comment: See my updated answer about how to submit a GET using URLSearchParams with FormData.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the page does not have a `form` element present at the time the following line of code runs:

```
 const formdata = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
```

If there are not any form elements in the page, `querySelector` will return `null`, which is not an object, which matches up with the error message. You can test by logging the form element (or null).

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
console.log('form', form);
```